# How do I pass a volatile variable to a function in c?

Tags: c, parameter-passing, volatile

I want to pass the following to a function in c:

```
#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400253FC))
```

The following seems to work well enough:

```
void ZeroRegister(unsigned long * _REG) 
{ 
    #define vReg (*((volatile unsigned long *)_REG))
    vReg = 0; 
}
```

Is there a better way to code this?
Or is my code flawed? Other than the compiler warning it generates.

Comment: why would you use a `#define` for this; you could as well write `*(volatile unsigned long *)_REG = 0;`

Comment: And which warning does it generate?

Comment: Note that names beginning with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for 'the implementation' — that means you should not use such names.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I suspect that the warnings are variants on `passing argument 1 of ‘ZeroRegister’ discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]` and `note: expected ‘long unsigned int *’ but argument is of type ‘volatile long unsigned int *’`.  That's what I get from a `main()` containing the line: `ZeroRegister(&GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R);` at any rate.

Comment: I used #define because it works, and I didn't know any better. The warning I get is warning:  #167-D: argument of type "volatile unsigned long *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned long *"
       ZeroRegister(&GPIO_PORTA_DATA_R); Thanks for the tip on the underscore prefix.

Answer (score 5):

You write your function so it expects a pointer to volatile memory, and that way you can avoid warnings (and there's no need for an extra macro in the function):

```
#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400253FC))

static void ZeroRegister(volatile unsigned long *REG)
{
    *REG = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    ZeroRegister(&GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R);
    return 0;
}
```

On Mac OS X 10.11.4 with GCC 5.3.0, that compiles cleanly with the command line shown (source file is `vui.c`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c vui.c
$
```

Omitting the `volatile` from the function parameter leads to warnings (line numbers and variable names do not match the code above; they were generated from an earlier version of the code):

```
…
vui.c: In function ‘main’:
vui.c:11:18: error: passing argument 1 of ‘ZeroRegister’ discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]
     ZeroRegister(&GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R);
                  ^
vui.c:3:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int *’ but argument is of type ‘volatile long unsigned int *’
 void ZeroRegister(unsigned long * _REG)
```

Note that the compiling code above avoids using a name reserved for the implementation.  All names starting with an underscore and a capital letter (or another underscore) are reserved for the implementation.  See ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers:

> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great solution. Volatile refers to the contents of _REG, not its address - right?                                                           static void ZeroRegister(volatile unsigned long *REG)
{
    *REG = 0;
}

Comment: Yes, that `volatile` says the object pointed at is `volatile`.  If the pointer was itself volatile, the notation would be `void ZeroRegister(unsigned long * volatile REG)`.  This is similar to `const`.

Comment: Note that you use back-ticks around `code` in comments.

Answer (score 3):

You pass it the same way as you would pass any other variable, you just need to add the `volatile` qualifier to the argument list:

```
void ZeroRegister(volatile unsigned long * _REG) 
{ 
    *_REG = 0; 
}
```

There's no need to attempt any preprocessor macro tricks.

Comment: (And then as Jonathan Leffler pointed out, `_Xnnnn` names are reserved for the implementation).